# "ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list" in Python, but it exists

Tags: python, string-parsing

I want to use Python to pull the username from an email address. The solution I thought of was to append the email address into a list, find the index of the `@` symbol, and then slice the list until I found the index.

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python<br/>
email = raw_input("Please enter your e-mail address: ")
email_list = []
email_list.append(email)
at_symbol_index = email_list.index("@")
email_username = email_list[0:at_symbol_index]
print email_username
```

But, everytime I run the script, it returns the error:

```
ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are making a list containing the string, so unless the string entered is `"@"`, then it is not in the list.

To fix, simply don't add the email address to a list. You can perform these operations on a string directly.

As a note, you might want to check out [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) instead, or [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
email_username, _, email_host = email.partition("@")
```

Comment: Also the str.partition you mentioned is very useful!

Comment: It's one of those little hidden pieces of useful from the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You add the entire e-mail address to a list. Did you perhaps mean

```
email_list = list(email)
```

which adds the *characters* of `email` (as opposed to the whole string at once). But even this is unnecessary, as strings can be sliced / indexed much like lists (so you don't need a list at all in this case).

An easier way to determine the username of an e-mail address would probably be

```
email.split("@")[0]
```